# how to design SCORM package with conditional loading of next page

Tags: scorm, sequencing

I am pretty new in SCORM course designing. I have a requirement to design a course as below

On first page collect use input: Are you student ?

If yes , load student exercise
If not , load research exercise

I am unable to understand how to achieve this in SCORM . I am use eXe XHTML editor for designing the course package and then importing it as SCORM 1.2. Then, to verify I load hte package on SCORM cloud.

Can someone guide me for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

SCORM 1.2 doesn't have sequencing rules. If you must use SCORM 1.2, then your best bet is to have only one SCO and manage the navigation through the course in JavaScript. Basically you have one SCO that acts as a player and loads the appropriate exercise based on whether the user is a student.

In the manifest you'd have one SCO under the organization, and for its resources you'd have the SCO href point to your "player" page.

```
...
<organizations default = "Course001">
    <organization identifier = "MyCourse">
        <title>SCORM 1.2 My Course</title>
        <item identifier="I_SCO1" identifierref="R_SCO01">
            <title>SCO 1</title>
        </item>
    </organization>
</organizations>
<resources>
    <resource identifier="R_SCO01" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="sco" href="scos/playerSCO.html">
        <file href="scos/playerSCO.html"/>
        <file href="scos/studentSCO1.html"/>
        <file href="scos/researchSCO1.html"/>
        ...
    </resource>
</resources>
...
```

If you can use SCORM 2004 then you have sequencing options. You can do conditional sequencing based on global variables called Global Objectives; you can use choice navigation events to move throughout the course; or in the latest version (4th Edition) you can issue jump navigation events to go to specific SCOs.

ADL made a developer's guide for SCORM 2004 that also includes some recipes. The Menu or Prerequisite recipes should get you going in the right direction. http://www.adlnet.gov/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/SCORM_Users_Guide_for_Programmers.pdf

Comment: I was able to create the sequencing and get published course as SCORM 2.1. I was trying with "My Udutu".